# I like to record video from FMS in another directory

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-media-server

I like to record video from my webcam via flash media server 4.
When I try to record the video, flash media server will put the recorded video in it's root's directory. for example (D:\Program Files\Adobe\Flash Media Server 4 applications\sample\streams_definst_\myvideo.flv).

But I need to change this directory to (E:\myvideos\video.flv)

Please kindly advise me.

Comment: You need to configure your FMS server/application. It's been years since I looked at this, so giving this as a comment rather than formal answer. But you probably just need to specify a value for the `<storageDir>` tag in the application's XML configuration file, as seen in the [documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flashmediaserver/3.0/docs/help.html?content=Book_Part_36_admin_1.html).

Comment: I can't seem to directly link to the right page, but if you follow the link above and drill down into: Configuring the server --> Configuring  content storage --> Setting the location... you will see what I'm referring to.